# I want to test ViewModel for my android app. The view model is regarding displaying posts in an app

Tags: unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-espresso

The app is written in Kotlin and Compose. I am testing the app using Espresso(JUnit4). I have tested the activities but I'm facing issues regarding testing ViewModels. I have attached the code written for the activities and ViewModel. Please help me in testing the project.

The code for FeedScreenViewModel is given below:-

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.paging.cachedIn
import com.amplitude.android.Amplitude
import com.kotlang.auth.login.UserProfileProto
import com.navachar.neptune.data.respository.FeedRepository
import com.navachar.neptune.data.db.entities.Post
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharingStarted
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class FeedScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    // TODO: Make this private
val amplitude: Amplitude,
private val feedRepository: FeedRepository,
): ViewModel() 
{

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "FeedScreenViewModel"
}

val profile = feedRepository.getProfile().stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
    initialValue = UserProfileProto.getDefaultInstance()
)

val feedPagingFlow = feedRepository.feedPagingFlow()
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)

/**
 * Adds or removes like from the given post
 *
 * @param post the post to update like for
 * @param isLiked the updated like state
 */
fun togglePostLike(post: Post, isLiked: Boolean) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        feedRepository.setPostLike(post, isLiked)
    }
  }
}
```

The code for FeedScreen is:-

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalProvider
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.testTag
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.paging.LoadState
import androidx.paging.compose.LazyPagingItems
import androidx.paging.compose.collectAsLazyPagingItems
import androidx.paging.compose.items
import com.amplitude.android.Amplitude
import com.kotlang.auth.login.UserProfileProto
import com.navachar.neptune.R
import 
com.navachar.neptune.presentation.screens.main.feed.actionscreens.post.PostActivity
import com.navachar.neptune.presentation.screens.main.feed.components.ErrorMessage
import com.navachar.neptune.presentation.screens.main.feed.components.PagingFooter
import com.navachar.neptune.presentation.screens.main.feed.components.Post
import com.navachar.neptune.presentation.screens.main.profile.ProfileActivity
import com.navachar.neptune.data.db.entities.Post
import com.navachar.neptune.data.db.entities.User
import com.navachar.neptune.data.db.entities.PostFull

const val TAG8="feed"

@Composable
fun FeedScreen(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
viewModel: FeedScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

val context = LocalContext.current

val profile by viewModel.profile.collectAsState()
val pagingItems = viewModel.feedPagingFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

FeedScreen(
    modifier = modifier,
    pagingItems = pagingItems,
    openCreatePostScreen = {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, PostActivity::class.java))
    },
    toggleLike = viewModel::togglePostLike,
    openPostDetails = { post ->
        Intent(
            context,
            CommentActivity::class.java,
        ).apply {
            putExtra("activity", "MainActivity")
            putExtra("postId", post.id)

            context.startActivity(this)
        }
    },
    sharePost = {
        shareContent(
            it,
            profile,
            viewModel.amplitude,
            context,
        )
    },
    openProfile = { user ->
        context.startActivity(
            Intent(
                context,
                ProfileActivity::class.java
            ).apply {
                putExtra("UserId", user.id)
            }
        )
    },
    onRequestOpenUrl = { url ->
        context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
    }
 )
}

@Composable
private fun FeedScreen(
modifier: Modifier,
pagingItems: LazyPagingItems<PostFull>,
openCreatePostScreen: () -> Unit,
toggleLike: (post: Post, isLiked: Boolean) -> Unit,
openPostDetails: (post: Post) -> Unit,
sharePost: (post: PostFull) -> Unit,
openProfile: (user: User) -> Unit,
onRequestOpenUrl: (url: String) -> Unit,
) {
Scaffold(
    modifier = modifier,
    content = {
        Feed(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it),
            pagingItems = pagingItems,
            toggleLike = toggleLike,
            openPostDetails = openPostDetails,
            sharePost = sharePost,
            openProfile = openProfile,
            onRequestOpenUrl = onRequestOpenUrl,
        )
    },

    bottomBar = {
        BottomBar(onClick = openCreatePostScreen)
    }
  )
}

@Composable
private fun Feed(
modifier: Modifier,
pagingItems: LazyPagingItems<PostFull>,
toggleLike: (post: Post, isLiked: Boolean) -> Unit,
openPostDetails: (post: Post) -> Unit,
sharePost: (post: PostFull) -> Unit,
openProfile: (user: User) -> Unit,
onRequestOpenUrl: (url: String) -> Unit,
) {

 when (val refreshState = pagingItems.loadState.refresh) {
    is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
        FeedLazyList(
            modifier = modifier.testTag(TAG8),
            pagingItems = pagingItems,
            openPostDetails = openPostDetails,
            openProfile = openProfile,
            sharePost = sharePost,
            toggleLike = toggleLike,
            onRequestOpenUrl = onRequestOpenUrl,
        )
    }

    is LoadState.Loading -> {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier,
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }

    is LoadState.Error -> {
        ErrorMessage(
            modifier = modifier,
            error = refreshState.error,
            onRetry = pagingItems::retry,
        )
    }
  }
}

@Composable
private fun FeedLazyList(
modifier: Modifier,
pagingItems: LazyPagingItems<PostFull>,
openPostDetails: (post: Post) -> Unit,
openProfile: (user: User) -> Unit,
sharePost: (post: PostFull) -> Unit,
toggleLike: (post: Post, isLiked: Boolean) -> Unit,
onRequestOpenUrl: (url: String) -> Unit,
) {
  LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier
) {
    items(pagingItems) { post ->
        if (post != null) {
            Post(
                post = post,
                openPostDetails = { openPostDetails(post.post) },
                openProfile = {
                    if (post.author != null) {
                        openProfile(post.author)
                    }
                },
                onSharePost = { sharePost(post) },
                onToggleLike = {
                    toggleLike(post.post, it)
                },
                onRequestOpenUrl = onRequestOpenUrl,
            )
        } else {
            // TODO: Show a shimmer placeholder for post
        }
    }

    item {
        PagingFooter(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            pagingItems = pagingItems
        )
    }
 }
}

@Composable
private fun BottomBar(
onClick: () -> Unit
) {
Row(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable(onClick = onClick)
        .padding(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(24.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_account),
            contentDescription = "",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = stringResource(R.string.post_something),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
        )
    }
 }
}

private fun shareContent(
post: PostFull,
profile: UserProfileProto,
amplitude: Amplitude,
context: Context
) {
 // TODO: Separate the amplitude logic from UI
val eventName = "CTA_Post_Share"
val eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val userId = profile.loginId
val loadTime = ""
val postTag = post.post.tags.joinToString()
val postContentType = if (post.media.isEmpty()) "Text" else "Media"
val postId = post.post.id
amplitude.track(
    eventType = eventName,
    eventProperties = mapOf(
        Pair("Event_Time", eventTime),
        Pair("Screen_Load_Time", loadTime),
        Pair("User_ID", userId),
        Pair("Post_Tag", postTag),
        Pair("Post_Content_Type", postContentType),
        Pair("Post_ID", postId)
    )
)

// TODO: Localise the share content
val shareContent = "${post.author?.name} Posted at Urvar:\n\n" +
        "${post.post.body.take(200)}...\n\n" +
        "Read More: http://www.urvar.com/post/${post.post.id}"

val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND

    putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        shareContent
    )
    type = "text/plain"
}
 val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
 context.startActivity(shareIntent)
}
```

Please help me test this viewmodel.

The code generated by Test for this View model is:-

```
class FeedScreenViewModelTest {


@Before
fun setUp() {
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
}

@Test
fun getProfile() {
}

@Test
fun getFeedPagingFlow() {
}

@Test
fun togglePostLike() {
}

  @Test
  fun getAmplitude() {
  }
}
```

Please tell me what to write inside these functions.